# CSV Two Column List With Spaces. Need everything before or everything after in two separate variables

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, cut

I have a CSV list that is two columns (col1 is Share Name, col2 is file system path). I need two variables for either everything BEFORE the comma, or everything AFTER the column. My issue is that either column potentially has spaces, and even though these are quoted in the output, my script isn't handling them properly.

CSV:
ShareName,/path/to/sharename
"Share with spaces",/path/to/sharewithspaces
ShareWithSpace,"/path/to/share with spaces"

I was using this awk statement to get either field 1 or field 2:

`echo $line | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}'`

BUT, I soon realized that it wasn't handling the spaces properly, even when passing that command to a variable and quoting the variable.

So, then after googling my brain out, I was trying this:

`echo $line | cut -d, -f2`

Which works, EXCEPT when echoing the variable $line. If I echo the string, it works perfectly, but unfortunately I'm using this in a while/read/do.

I am fairly certain my issue is having to define fields and having whitespace, but I really only need before or after a comma.

Here's the stripped down version so there's no sensitive data.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash  

ssh <ip> <command> > "2_shares.txt"  

<command> > "1_shares.txt"  



file1="1_shares.txt"  
file2="2_shares.txt"  


while read -r line  
do  
  share=`echo "$line" | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}'`  
  path=`echo "$line" | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}'`  
    if grep "$path" $file2 > /dev/null;  
      then  
        :  
      else  
        echo "SHARE NEEDS CREATED FOR $line"  
        case $path in  
          *)  
          blah blah blah  
          ;;  
        esac  
    fi  
done < "$file1"
```

Comment: you mean this `cut -d, -f2 <<< "$line"` . Why you use `while/read` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do like this,

```
awk -F',' '{print $2}' file
```

To skip the first line.

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1{print $2}' file
```

Comment: This is essentially what I was doing. It works if I put single quotes around the line, however, the line is being read as a variable ($line). If I put single quotes around the variable, it won't read it as a variable anymore.

Comment: variable expansion would occur only within the double quotes not within the single quotes. TRy `awk -F',' '{print $2}' <<< "$line"`

Comment: Avinash, still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is simply that you aren't quoting your shell variables. ALWAYS quote shell variables unless you have a very specific reason not to and are fully aware of all of the consequences.

I strongly suspect the rest of your script is completely wrong in it's approach since you apparently didn't know to quote variables and are talking about shell loops and echoing one line at time to awk so please do post a followup question if you'd like help.

Comment: I've added a stripped down version of the script I'm working on. I don't think it's possible for me to quote my variable any more than I have already.

Comment: I see you're now quoting `$line` so that's better but you still need to quote `$file2`. You're missing `IFS=` between `while read` (should be `while IFS= read`). You should be using `grep -q -m1`. The awk script should probably be output contents that get stored in an array or having it's output piped to `while read share path` with appropriate IFS, etc. As written the whole thing should be a single, simple awk script anyway though - depends what's happening in the parts that you removed.

Comment: I was able to redo my script with python and split the line much easier.

Comment: and I'm sure if you redid it in awk you'd be able to do it much easier still but that's not what you asked for and didn't provide enough information for us to help you there's nothing we could do.